# Javascript with the nasa API problem accessing certain elements

Tags: javascript, api

So i have a JSON object.

```
jsonData
```

if i console log it i can see that it contains what i understand a 2D array called `near_earth_objects` in this 2D array there is a property called `absolute_magnitude_h` that i want to access.

if i copy the property path i get this

near_earth_objects['2015-09-07']['0'].absolute_magnitude_h

so i thought doing

```
console.log(jsonData.near_earth_objects[2015-09-07][0].absolute_magnitude_h);
```

would print that variable sadly this just gives me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

link to test this API https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3542519?api_key=DEMO_KEY

Comment: `2015-09-07` is treated as the equation `2015 - 9 - 7` resulting in effectively getting `jsonData.near_earth_objects[1999]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a string for accessing a date like string. Otherwise it takes the result of the subtraction as key.

```
console.log(jsonData.near_earth_objects['2015-09-07'][0].absolute_magnitude_h);
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```